# find out what page the iframe is on

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a 'toolbar' on the top of my website, and the content of the page is an iframe.
How can I find out with javascript what the current URL of the iframe is?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be possible if the iframe is in a different domain, or otherwise violates the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). For example, if the page is at example.com/foo and the iframe is at example.org/bar, you cannot get the location.

If you are not violating the same origin policy, you can use something like this:

```
window.frames["iframeID"].location.href
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `window.frames[0].location.href` ?

Or if you know the `id` of the iframe, then `document.getElementById("iframe1").src` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "src" attribute.

for example window.frames["your_iframe"].src

Comment: this returns the src location. what if the user navigates from the original page location. i need the actual location the page is at..!

Comment: Yes, you'll want to check the location.href of the document, then.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUrl()
{
    var pageFrame = $find("frame_id_goes_here", document);
    if(pageFrame) {
        return pageFrame.location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the iframe is the first on the page:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('IFRAME')[0].contentDocument.location.href
```

Of course you could always just grab it by ID:

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').contentDocument.location.href
```

The `contentDocument` is the key.

Best of luck!